# why is this jquery code not working after refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading

I use an AJAX file for loading my web pages.
But after reloading the pages, if any JQuery code were available, it didn't work properly.
Please let me know how to change an AJAX code or how to reload JQuery code as well.

```
var xmlHttp;
function createRequest(){
  if(window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
}

function ajax(url){
  createRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatepage;
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function updatepage(){
    document.getElementById('load_ajax').innerHTML = "<div id='load_ajax' align='center'><img src='../images/loding.gif'><font dir ='ltr'>...لطفا کمی صبر کنید<font></div>";
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('load_ajax').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
```

For example, I want to use Jquery Validation code for loading this page,
But after reloading, it didn't work.... without it, it reloads like I want.

```
$.validator.addMethod("NumbersOnly", function(value, element) {
       return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-\+]+$/i.test(value);
   }, "فقط عدد وارد کنید");
    $("#form1").validate();
```

Comment: if you're using jquery, why do you have a `function ajax()`?

Comment: It is not 1999 anymore, do not use font tags.

Comment: i'v two pages , one of them is ajax.js and the another one is validation.js , both of them reload well in a main page "index.php" , so other pages use ajax.js to show the contents .... now i  want to load pages that use JQuery, to load as well and show properly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using jquery you don't need that `ajax()` method, just use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which is much easier.

Secondly, from what i understand you want to load a page from another page using ajax, when you do that, you probably only load a portion of the page, so any script/css reference you have in the header of the page loaded by ajax is irrelevant.

what you need is to have jquery referenced in the loading page, so if you have page1 loading page2 , you should reference jquery in page1 not in page2.